# Minimum interval containing all the objects

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a set of objects, each of which is placed at several locations on a Natural number line: Find the smallest interval `[a, b]` containing all the objects.

Example: Consider 3 objects `A, B, C`

A is placed at `1, 5, 7`
B is placed at `2, 4, 6`
C is placed at `4, 8, 9`

The smallest interval that encompasses all the three objects is `[4, 5]`.

I can only think of `O(S^2)` solution where `S` is the minimal interval containing all the object locations i.e, `[1, 9]`.

Is there a better way to do this ?

PS : Note that multiple objects can be placed at the same location.

Comment: is there a limit on the number of different objects you place?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev its bounded and usually a small number ( < 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort all the data points in ascending order (nlogn time).
Traverse these data points from the left.

Keep track of the following:
1. For each type of object, maintain an entry of the coordinate of last object found (maybe through a hashmap for fast operation).
2. Minimum interval length found till now.
3. The coordinate of the earliest element in the list. This is to keep track of the start of current interval.

Whenever you encounter an object,
1. Update its entry in the maintained list.
2. Check whether the coordinate of earliest element has been updated. If so, then calculate the new interval length and update the minimum interval length if the new one is smaller.

**You will first need to ascertain that you have encountered all types of objects to calculate the first valid minimum interval length. You can do that by a counter.**

If the number of different types of elements is bounded and small, then the order of complexity is O(nlogn) where n is the total number of data points.

Comment: i've essentially came up with the same solution (left to right sweep with start and end pointers) but I was too lazy to write it here :) Thanks.

Comment: _"Sort all the data points in ascending order (nlogn time)."_ What is __n__ here? It seems, `n` is number of points for each object. That neams you'll have to do that `m` times, where `m` is count of objects. So complexity will be `O(m x n x log(n))` . Or else, if it's about sorting them across all points, that will be `O(m x n log(m x n))`

Comment: @AlmaDo I mentioned towards the end, that n is the total number of data points. Also, OP mentioned in comments that the number of types of objects (m) is small and bounded. This is why I neglected its complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in O(N) using 2 indices while going through the list. (Lets call them left and right).

You start with both of them in position 1, and then increment right until [left,right] has all the elements. You know that this is the minimum interval starting in left that has all the elements. Now increment left. Now increment right again until you have all the elements. (NOTE, many times you don't even have to increment). Get the minimum out of all the complete intervals and you have your answer.

This works because if you know [left,right] is the minimum interval starting at left, the interval starting at left+1 will have it's right >= the last right.

This is O(N) because you add the elements of a location once, and delete them once.

You'll need to use a hash to count the unique elements.